# New to java: I'm not sure how to store the objects in the arrays after it is created. The program gets rid of it, making it null

Tags: java, arrays

The main objective was to have a lake and add fish objects to it, which have details about their weight etc. But however, every time a new fish is created, the previous object appears as `null` instead of its location, which I could use my `getName` to get the name.

```
package com. company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lake l = new Lake("jersey", 1, 2, 3,4 );
        l.addFish("carp", 20, 1);
        l.addFish("josh",20,1);

        Lake n = new Lake("york",1,2,4,20);
        n.addFish("catfish",20,30);
        n.addFish("tot",20,30);
        n.addFish("salmon",20,30);
        n.addFish("shrimp",20,30);
        n.addFish("swordfish",20,30);


    }
}
```

```
package com. company;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lake {
    private String name;
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double depth;
    private final int amountOfFish;
    private int currentFishAmount = 0 ;

    Lake(String name, double length, double width, double depth, int amountOfFish)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.amountOfFish = amountOfFish;
    }

    public void addFish (String name, double length, double weight)
    {
        Fish fishInLake []  = new Fish[amountOfFish];
        fishInLake[currentFishAmount]= new Fish(name, length, weight);
        System.out.println("Lake: " + this.name +  "|" + "Fish:" + ""+ fishInLake[currentFishAmount].getName() + fishInLake[currentFishAmount].getLength());
        System.out.println(currentFishAmount);
        currentFishAmount++;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fishInLake));
    }
```

```
}
package com.company;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Fish {
    private String name;
    private double length;
    private double weight;


    Fish (String name, double length, double weight){
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

   public String getName(){
        return this.name;
   }

   public double getLength(){
        return this.length;
   }

   public double getWeight(){
        return this.weight;
   }

}
```

The main objective was to have a lake and add fish objects to it, which have details about their weight etc. But however, every time a new fish is created, the previous object appears as `null` instead of its location, which I could use my `getName` to get the name.

Comment: In your own words, at the top of the `Lake` class, where you write `private String name;`, what do you think that does? Can you think of a way to use the same technique to make the `fishInLake` stay around?

Comment: In your own words, when you `import java.lang.reflect.Array;` and `import java.util.Arrays;`, what do you think these are for? What happened when you tried omitting them?

Comment: The `fishInLake` array is created every time you add a new fish. With arrays you need to know up front how many items you would like to store in them. Try an ArrayList instead and add the fishes to it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks for the help. But I really can't think of how to do that. I tried to work around it but It still resulted in the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, to make your output a bit more readable, add a toString() method in your Fish class:

```
 public String toString(){
    return this.name;
  }
```

Next, since you want the array to be saved every time a new fish is added to the lake, we want to make the array a private instance variable, and then initialize it in our constructor:

```
package com. company;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lake {
    private String name;
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double depth;
    private final int amountOfFish;
    private int currentFishAmount = 0 ;
    private Fish[] fishInLake;

    Lake(String name, double length, double width, double depth, int amountOfFish)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.amountOfFish = amountOfFish;
        this.fishInLake = new Fish[amountOfFish];
    }

    public void addFish (String name, double length, double weight)
    {
        fishInLake[currentFishAmount]= new Fish(name, length, weight);
        System.out.println("Lake: " + this.name +  "|" + "Fish:" + ""+ fishInLake[currentFishAmount].getName() + fishInLake[currentFishAmount].getLength());
        System.out.println(currentFishAmount);
        currentFishAmount++;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fishInLake));
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you have another question feel free to post another question and just let me know here so I get notified (can't guarantee I'll be able to answer it tho lol)

Comment: Thanks man, here's my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68673063/16602632

Comment: I posted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

better to create a *static* method or a **static Array**, otherwise every time that tries to insert data, the previous data will be disappearing, with a **static Array** the whole data will be there until program execution finish.