# New to Java: For some reason I get that the value is null in my for loop, but if I change i to 0 it is not null

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arr

The main problem is in the findFish method. I initialized i=0 in the for loop, but that gives me the error "Cannot invoke "com.company.Fish.getName()" because "this.fishInLake[x]" is null". However if I change i to for instance 0, it gives me false, which is the right result. Im a bit

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lake {
    private String name;
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double depth;
    private final int amountOfFish;
    private int currentFishAmount = 0 ;
    private Fish[] fishInLake;

    Lake(String name, double length, double width, double depth, int amountOfFish)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.amountOfFish = amountOfFish;
        this.fishInLake = new Fish[amountOfFish];
    }

    public void addFish (String name, double length, double weight)
    {
        fishInLake[currentFishAmount]= new Fish(name, length, weight);
        System.out.println("Lake: " + this.name +  "|" + "Fish:" + ""+ fishInLake[currentFishAmount].getName() + fishInLake[currentFishAmount].getLength());
        System.out.println(currentFishAmount);
        currentFishAmount++;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fishInLake));
    }

    **public boolean findFish(String fishName)
    {
        boolean isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < fishInLake.length; i ++)
        {
            if (fishInLake[i].getName() == fishName)
            {
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
        return isFound;
    }**


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because when you compare a null item using == or the equals() method, your code will throw an error. Also note that when working with Strings, you should use the .equals() method and not ==

Here is a sample test case:

```
    System.out.println(n.findFish("shrimp"));
    System.out.println(n.findFish("babbgdshogj"));
```

The expected output would be:

```
true
false
```

The following code achieves that by making sure that the element in the array is not null:

```
public boolean findFish(String fishName)
{
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < fishInLake.length; i ++)
    {
        if (fishInLake[i] != null && fishInLake[i].getName().equals(fishName))
        {
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
    return isFound;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! If I may ask, how did you learn so much about Java?

Comment: Last year, I took AP Computer Science A at my highschool. I also started participating in USACO, a coding competition, which was really hard at first (and still is) but helped me understand classes and object oriented programming a lot more.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Im taking APCSA this year. Doing this work for it.

Comment: Thanks! I hope its not to hard :)

Comment: If you're already doing this stuff and the school year hasn't even started you'll be fine. Are you a rising senior?

Comment: I'm going into my sophomore year.

Comment: OH I'm so stupid I read the other message as "I'm only one year older than you"

Answer (score 2):

> `this.fishInLake = new Fish[amountOfFish];`

This makes an array that can store the pointer to `amountOfFish` fishes.

**It makes no fish at all**.

You now have an array that is currently storing `amountOfFish` `null` values.

If you want actual fish, make a for loop `for (int i = 0; i < fishInLake.length; i++) fishInLake[i] = new Fish(...);`

`fishInLake.length` returns the # of slots that the array has. It doesn't go through and count the amount of actual fish pointers that are in there.

> `fishInLake[i].getName()`

The dot operator dereferences. If you try to dereference null, a NullPointerException occurs.

> `fishInLake[i].getName() == ...`

This compares pointers. It is not what you want. You are interested in whether the names are the same. You want `fishInLake[i].getName().equals(....)` instead.

Every time you call `addFish`, you create a new fish object, and then you replace whatever is at slot `currentFishAmount` with a pointer to it.

Given that this `currentFishAmount` starts at `0` and is incremented everytime, this roughly does the job of 'adding a fish'.

However, your findFish method looks through every available slot and dereferences the reference it finds there. It should be looking only from 0 to `currentFishAmount` (which would imply not looking at anything if no fishes have been added yet, but that's be the right move here).

Comment: Thanks for the help man. Also what would you recommend to do instead of the currentFishAmount? Im new to all of this, thanks once again.

Comment: No, `currentFishAmount` is right. You need to be using it in your `findFish` method - you currently are using `fishInLake.length`, replace it with `currentFishAmount`. And fix the `==` to `.equals` on that getName comparison.